# jQuery add another function to AJAX call or CSS solution?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have an AJAX call in a PHP file that replaces the content of a div, depending on which button is clicked. It works beautifully. Now that I have that functionality working, I would like to change the background color of the button from gray to green, when it is clicked, and have it stay green until another button is clicked, then have that one turn green.

Here is the javascript for the AJAX:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function ChangeContent1()
{
  $("#table_area_dripPSZ1").load("zone1PS.php");
}
function ChangeContent2()
{
  $("#table_area_dripPSZ1").load("zone2PS.php");
}
function ChangeContent3()
{
  $("#table_area_dripPSZ1").load("zone3PS.php");
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML for one of the buttons:

```
<button
    type="button"
    name="z3"
    onclick="ChangeContent3()">
    Zone 3
</button>
```

Here is the CSS I used for changing the button to green:

```
button:active {
background-color: #3DAE48;
}

button:focus {
background-color: #3DAE48;
}

button:focus:active {
background-color: #3DAE48;
}
```

The problem is that the above code works fine in browsers on the PC, but only works in Chrome on the Mac. For Safari and Firefox on the Mac, and all browsers in IOS, it doesn't work. I haven't been able to test it yet in IE.

It seems that the solution is to use jQuery to add another function to the onClick event. I found some viable jQuery code here on stackoverflow, but can't figure how or where to insert it. I've tried pretty much every combination I could think of.

I'm good with PHP, HTML, and CSS, but am a complete newbie at JavaScript and AJAX. It was a feat for me to get the AJAX working. But this turning the button green and having it stay green until another is clicked has really got me in a tizzy. Thank you so much in advance for help with this.

Comment: You should get rid of inline javascript handlers like `onclick="ChangeContent3()"` on your button, and instead use javascript to _attach_ a handler to the element (button).  Since you're already using jQuery it is _super easy_ to do. Then move all your javascript into its own `.js` file so it isn't mixed in with your php.

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/egdpj827/1/) demonstrating John Svensson's answer, also showing that the HTML/PHP, the Javascript, and the CSS are kept separate.

Comment: Great input, @StephenP! Thank you so much for doing this. I can see that it is the most efficient use of the code. It will serve me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to bind the buttons to a click event and add a class that sets the `background-color`

```
$('button').click(function () {
   $('button').removeClass('btn-active');
   $(this).addClass('btn-active'); 
});
```

First we remove the class btn-active from all buttons, and then add the class to the button we clicked.
If you have multiple buttons on your page, that should have this behavior you should probably add a class on those buttons, and change that events only listens to those button with that class.

Comment: I have  a question about this: 1. Where in the file do I put this code? I'm not sure whether to put it in the head, in the body before the buttons, or at the end of the file right before the ending body tag.

Comment: Right before the ending body tag is usually the best place. Make sure you wrap the code in ```$(document).ready(function () { // Code here });``` to make sure the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

Comment: Thank you, @John. This totally works too. I'll sock this away for future use in this project. I already marked another answer as the correct one, so I am up-voting yours. Thank you again.

Comment: this actually ended up being the best solution, since the other solution kept the button green, even when other buttons were clicked. By I didn't ask for that in my question, so I wouldn't tell the other person his answer was wrong. Both answers were correct, but yours was more relevant to my need.

Comment: Glad it helped! In general you should try avoid inline scripts, and have them in a logical place at the end of your document, this makes sure the scripts are loaded last, but also by placing code in the document.ready assures that the DOM is ready for manipulation.

Comment: @JohnSvensson - _"right before the ending body tag"_ is not necessary when using `$(document).ready(...)`. The reason people put js at the end of the body is to make sure all the elements exist before the javascript runs... but document.ready doesn't run until the DOM is ready anyway. The best place to put the (javascript) code is _**in a separate .js file**_ then put a link to that file in the `<head>` of your document. `<script src="/js/yourscript.js"></script>`

Comment: ... and @Lori ... I agree this is a much better answer, and you can change which one is the accepted answer. It doesn't matter that you marked the other, you can un-mark it and pick this one instead.

Comment: Thank you, @StephenP. I didn't know I could change the correct answer. I've done that. Also, thank you for the JS Fiddle example. I appreciate you taking the time to do so. This forum is such a great way to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CSS, just replace

```
<button
    type="button"
    name="z3"
    onclick="ChangeContent3()">
    Zone 3
</button>
```

By

```
<button
    type="button"
    name="z3"
    onclick="$(this).css('background-color','#3DAE48'); ChangeContent3();">
    Zone 3
</button>
```

With this, you'll change the buttons' background color with jQuery

Comment: Sorry. Don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: this seems like a good solution, but it threw my PHP all out of whack. I got the following error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'background' (T_STRING)

Comment: Replace the ' in my answer for \' @Lori

Comment: That works! Thank you so much, @Luis! I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you click another button the other button you clicked earlier would still be green though.

Comment: That's what I think he wants @John - to turn the buttons green as they're clicked